# Question about what (TS.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.Yes) does

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that out of the blue started giving me errors (shown below).  I think the problem is that the if statement below is never true.  Could somebody explain what the if file is looking for?  This occurs right as a screen is opened right in front of another.  I thought this would check if the new screen is opened, but the if statement never comes true.

```
private void TeachSensor_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TeachSensor_OPC();
  UserProgram.Enabled = false;
  User_Program_Teach_Senson TS = new User_Program_Teach_Senson(this);
  if (TS.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.Yes)
  {
    OperationInitialize();
    SetupMode_Button_Click(null, null);
    SetupMode_Button.Focus();
    PartCounterOPC.RunWorkerAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: `ShowDialog` is modal, so it waits on the screen for the user to close the form.  If the results of the user pressing the designated "Yes" button, the result is true.  You didn't post anything about "errors".

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog()` is a function of a form used to show the form as a dialog. The result of the function is returned when the dialog is *closed*. A dialog box with a message prompt would be set up to return a `DialogResult` value based on what the user did in the dialog box (e.g. clicked `OK`, returns `DialogResult.OK`; clicked Cancel or close button returns `DialogResult.OK`; same for `Yes`, `No`, etc.). In your case, the `If` statement would not be evaluated until the dialog box is closed.

Therefore, any code to run for initializing the dialog box must be inside the dialog form. After the user finishes the task in the dialog box, a result is returned by setting a value to `Form.DialogResult` in the dialog box (e.g. `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK`).